# CakePHP Update image Upload

Tags: php, cakephp

So I have this image upload function where I can upload an image and update the image path on the Database. The Problem is the image is not uploading and not updating on the Database. All other records were successfully updated but not the image. Please help.

Below is my code

**edit.ctp**

```
 <form id="form">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->base ?>/uploads/employees/{{ data.Employee.image }}" width="110" height="100" class="user-image photo">
            <ul class="list-group w110px">
              <span class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm btn-file">
                Choose File 
                <input id="employeeImage" onchange="readURL(this)" name="picture" class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
              </span>
            </ul>
    </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" ng-click="update()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> SAVE</button>

</form>
```

**controller.js**

```
 app.controller('EmployeeEditController', function($scope, $routeParams, Employee, Select) {
 $('#form').validationEngine('attach');
 $scope.employeeId = $routeParams.id;

// load employee
$scope.load = function() {
 Employee.get({ id: $scope.employeeId }, function(e) {
   $scope.data = e.data;
 });
// department selection
Select.get({ code: 'departments' }, function(e) {
  $scope.departments = e.data;
});

Select.get({ code: 'positions' }, function(e) {
  $scope.positions = e.data;
});

  // employee-types selection
 Select.get({ code: 'employee-types' }, function(e) {
   $scope.types = e.data;
 });

}
 $scope.load();

 // update employee
 $scope.update = function() {
    valid = $("#form").validationEngine('validate');
 if (valid) {
  Employee.update({ id: $scope.employeeId } ,$scope.data, function(e)      {
    if (e.ok) {
      $.gritter.add({
        title: 'Successful!',
        text: e.msg
      });
      window.location = '#/employees';
    }else {
      $.gritter.add({
        title: 'Warning!',
        text: e.msg
       });
     }
   });
  }
 }
});
```

**api.php**

```
public function edit($id = null) {

$employeeImage = @$_FILES['picture']['name'];
if (!empty($employeeImage)) {
  $attachmentExt = pathinfo($employeeImage, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $this->request->data['Employee']['image'] =  $this->Employee->nextId() . '.' . $attachmentExt;
}

 if($this->Employee->save($this->request->data)) {
  $response = array(
    'ok'   => true,
    'msg'  => 'Employee has been added.',
    'data' => $this->request->data['Employee']
  );
} else {
  $response = array(
    'ok'  => false,
    'msg' => 'Employee cannot be saved this time.'
  );
}

if (!empty($employeeImage)) {
    $path = "uploads/employees";
    if(!file_exists('uploads')) mkdir('uploads');
    if(!file_exists('uploads/employees')) mkdir('uploads/employees');
    if(!file_exists($path)) mkdir($path);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $path . '/' . $this->request->data['Employee']['image']);
}

$this->set(array(
    'response'   => $response,
    '_serialize' => 'response'
));
}
```

Comment: help please?? anyone??

Comment: What is the filesize of your upload file? Have you checked whether the upload file size doesn't exceed your php.ini settings `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`? What have you tried to debug the upload? Any error messages in the log files?

Comment: Hi, there are no errors on the log files.. the size i'm uploading is less than a megabyte.. no errors are being displayed when I run the scipt.. it shows successful but there is no file on the uploads folder..

Comment: Maybe a chmod problem - Is your 'tmp' directory and the destination folder writeable? Have you check both 'tmp' and error logfiles (general PHP system folders as well as in your CakePHP app)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('Post')) {
            $this->Post->create();
           $filename = WWW_ROOT. DS . 'upload'.DS.$this->data['Post']['doc_file']['name']; 
           move_uploaded_file($this->data['Post']['doc_file']['tmp_name'],$filename);  

        $this->request->data['Post']['image'] = $this->data['Post']['doc_file']['name'];
        unset( $this->request->data['Post']['doc_file'] );

        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Saved successfully',true), 'default', array('class' => ' success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {           
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Not saved. Please try again',true), 'default', array('class' => 'failer '));
        }
        }   
    }
```